# How to find the amazon MWS WSDL

Tags: amazon-web-services, process, wsdl, integration, sap-pi

I'm trying to create a integration between SAP PI and Amazon MWS to get order information back on a periodical timeframe, to process the orders into SAP as `ORDERS05` IDocs.

I don't seem to be able to locate the MWS WSDL to play about with in SOAPUI. Could anyone advise how I can find this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need to be able to use the [Orders API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/142-4352120-5443662?ie=UTF8&group=orders&section=orders&version=latest) for MWS should be right here:

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/index.html

Comment: Thankyou, i'm not sure if its good etiquette to ask another question, but that page you directed me to..I've been there before, it doesnt tell me whether I need a wsdl or what url i need to call to access the api functions. Sorry for the Noob level..

Comment: no, problem at all.  The easiest and fastest way is to download an SDK in either C#, PHP, or Java.  Those are at one of the above links.  You could also use the scratchpad for quick tests of the API, which would show you the full url that you would call. https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html

Comment: The mws scratchpad is useful, but have run into issues in finding the details i need to enter into the authentication section - theyre not all in one logical area are they? Am now getting error:  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>    i've googled it but not come up with anything - any input would be useful, thanks.

Comment: For the auth section, you need your seller ID (also called merchant ID), your AWSAccessKeyId and your Secret Key.  The latter two are part of your developer credentials that you get when you register as a developer.   If your development credentials are from your own seller central account, you don't need and MWSAuthToken.  That is if you provide your developer ID to another seller and they authorize you to develop for them.   You can read about developer credentials here: https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_IT/dev_guide/DG_Registering.html

Comment: FYI that is a bad error message, it's not very helpful, but it sounds like you have incorrect or invalid credentials.

Comment: Thanks, i've just confirmed with my 3rd party that im getting info from  that  AWS Access Key ID and Secret Key are correct. My developer id and mws details are correct. Still getting the 401 though :(.

Comment: I've got this working now, but how do i transpose this into soapui or postman? Could you please advise?